# file extensions in dirtree

Tags: dirtree

I am using `dirtree` to generate the tree structure for a directory.

The problem is I cannot use `.` between file name and file extension as it is
   acting as delimiter between two nodes in a tree.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. And it's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures))

Answer (score 4):

It works fine for me: The `.` is only used as a node delimiter if it's at the end of the line. Am I misunderstanding your question?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}
\dirtree{%
.1 /.
.2 bin.
.2 home.dir.
.3 jeancome.
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. It worked for me as well.

Comment: @Harsha: That's great! We'll probably close this as "too localized" then.