# How to print a dot followed by a space inside a DirTree node?

Tags: dirtree

The `dirtree` package uses a `.` followed by a whitespace as a sign to end a node. [See documentation, page 2](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/generic/dirtree/dirtree.pdf)

This usually works pretty good, but I'd like to print `correct format e.g. DD.MM.YYYY` as a node for my `DirTree`. This causes a problem as the character sequence `e.g.[SPACE]` seems to be interpreted as the termination sequence.

The error messages read `Use of \next doesn't match its definition` and `Undefined control sequence`

Is there a way to print `[dot][space]` without attempting to end the node? If there is none, are there other characters which can act as a space?

MWE to quickly reproduce:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}
  \dirtree{%
    .1 ROOT.
    .2 Level 2.
    .2 Correct format e.g. DD.MM.YYYY.
  }
\end{document}
```

The question [file extensions in dirtree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84751/105226) is related but the OP can remove the space after the dot, which I can not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to change every trailing space after a period to `~` or `\`+space, as shown here.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}
  \dirtree{%
    .1 ROOT.
    .2 Level 2.
    .2 Correct format e.g.~DD.MM.YYYY. %% or e.g.\ DD.MM.YYYY.
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! To add to this: It seems simply replacing the space with `~` seems to work as well and keeps the code a bit more simple

Comment: Oh, so it does! I thought I tried that, but I guess not. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Note that `~` prevent line breaking at that particular space.  On the other hand, I don't know whether line breaking is feasible at all inside the `\dirtree`.

Answer (score 4):

You could nest the expression containing dots in braces to “hide” them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}
  \dirtree{%
    .1 ROOT.
    .2 Level 2.
    .2 Correct format {e.g. DD.MM.YYYY}.
  }
\end{document}
```

It is also possible to introduce braces for all the nodes in the tree to convey a notion of consistency.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\begin{document}
  \dirtree{%
    .1 {ROOT}.
    .2 {Level 2}.
    .2 {Correct format e.g. DD.MM.YYYY}.
  }
\end{document}
```

The result is always the same.

[image]